# Class of languages recognised by a Forgetful Turing Machine

Tags: formal-languages, turing-machines

A Forgetful Turing Machine (FTM) operates just like a normal Turing machine except that, in every instruction (i.e., transition), the letter written in the tape cell is always the letter $a$, regardless of the current state and the current letter (although the read/write head is still allowed to move either Left or Right, according to the instruction). What class of languages is recognised by FTMs?

Is the language non-empty with only the letter $a$? Does this mean that it is regular since it can be represented by $aa^*$?

Comment: Your model can certainly simulate DFAs. Make sure you understand the definition of the language accepted by a forgetful Turing machine.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus since DFAs recognises regular languages, this also implies that FTMs is recognised by a regular language, right?

Comment: I’d say the implication goes the opposite way.

Comment: This is an interesting and somewhat tricky question but you seem not to understand the basic definition of a language recognized by a machine. Maybe it is better to ask the one who assigns this question to you for help.

Comment: @xskxzr I did but I still did not understand. Are there any hints on how to approach this question?

Comment: @xskxzr I don’t think your idea works. I would guess FTMs accept regular languages.

Comment: @xskxzr I don’t think so. When converting the input to your new representation, you erase most of it without ever reading it.

Comment: @xskxzr Each time you visit a cell, an $a$ is promptly written on it. You only control which way the head moves (and the states).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99028/discussion-between-xskxzr-and-yuval-filmus).

Comment: @YuvalFilmus will this machine halt?

Comment: Perhaps you should define your model more carefully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The class languages recognized by FTMs are the class of regular languages. A FTM can completely simulate a DFA, so each regular language can be recognized by a FTM. On the other hand, if we can prove each FTM recognizes a regular language, we have proved the assertion.

Given a FTM $F$ with the set of states $Q$, we use the [Myhill–Nerode theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myhill%E2%80%93Nerode_theorem) to show the language it recognizes is regular. Given a string $x$, we ask the following query:

1. If $F$ runs on $x$, does $F$ ever leave $x$ to the right? If so, in which state is $F$ when it first moves to the first position to the right of $x$? If not, does $F$ accept $x$?

... and the following $|Q|$ queries for each state $q\in Q$:

2. If $F$ runs on $\underbrace{a\cdots a}_\text{the number of $a$ = $|x|$}$, but is started on the rightmost $a$ and in state $q$, does $F$ ever leave the input to the right? If so, in which state is $F$ when it first moves to first position to the right of the input? If not, does $F$ accept the input finally?

We collect the strings that give the same answers to the $|Q|+1$ queries above into the same class. Since there are $(|Q|+2)^{|Q|+1}$ possible answers to the $|Q|+1$ queries above, there are only finite many classes. Next, we are going to prove that for any strings $x,y$ in the same class, i.e., that give the same answers to the $|Q|+1$ queries, for any string $z$, $F$ accepts either both or neither of $xz$ and $yz$, which completes the proof by the Myhill–Nerode theorem.

Consider that $F$ runs respectively on $xz$ and $yz$. Note the answers to query 1 are the same for $x$ and $y$, there are two cases:

1. $F$ never leaves $x$ to the right on $xz$, and $F$ never leaves $y$ to the right on $yz$. In this case, $F$ runs as if the inputs are respectively $x$ and $y$. Since the answers to query 1 are the same for $x$ and $y$, $F$ accepts either both or neither of $xz$ and $yz$.
2. $F$ ever leaves $x$ to the right on $xz$, and $F$ ever leaves $y$ to the right on $yz$. In this case, $F$ is in the same state when it first moves to the leftmost position of $z$, so $F$ behaves the same until it returns respectively to the rightmost position of $x$ and $y$. According to the definition of FTM, the input must become $a\cdots a$ when $F$ returns, and we can apply a recursive analysis according to query 2 (you can use mathematical induction to write a strict proof). As a result, $F$ accepts either both or neither of $xz$ and $yz$.

Of course, the analysis above assumes the tape of the FTM is restricted such that the head cannot leave the input to the left. The proof is similar without this assumption.